# How to parse texts outside XML tag?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I want to parse texts that appear in XML file but outside XML tags. in the attached example I would like to parse only the texts that is outside of `p` tag, such as `"FIELD OF THE TECHNOLOGY"` and `"DETAILED DESCRIPTION OF THE TECHNOLOGY"`.

An example of my XML file is:

```
<description>                        
FIELD OF THE TECHNOLOGY
<p>The present technology is directed ....</p>
<p>The present invention is.....</p>
<p>One promising approach has ...,</p>


DETAILED DESCRIPTION OF THE TECHNOLOGY
<p>The present tech provides, ....</p>
<p>A report by Kearse et al.,...</p>
</description>
```

Comment: thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Terminology

In your example, the `description` *element* has *mixed content*.  You're looking to extract the *text node* children of the `description` element. Identifying the right terminology is the first step to searching for answers (and narrowing overly broad questions).

### Parsing XML

**...with Java in general**

- [Best XML parser for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/373833/290085)
- [Which is the best library for XML parsing in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059224/which-is-the-best-library-for-xml-parsing-in-java)
- [How to retrieve element value of XML using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076910/how-to-retrieve-element-value-of-xml-using-java)
- [Is there an easier way to parse XML in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719261/is-there-an-easier-way-to-parse-xml-in-java)

**...with mixed content:**

- [Parsing Mixed-Content XML with SAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37820152/parsing-mixed-content-xml-with-sax)
- [Problems parsing XML in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16231687/290085)

**...choosing parsing technology:**

You can find many tutorials on [choosing a parsing technology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019509/what-are-the-differences-between-dom-sax-and-stax-xml-parsers), but XPath is particularly well-suited for selecting parts of an XML document, and there are libraries available for most languages.

**...via XPath, for example:**

This XPath,

```
//description/text()
```

will select all immediate text node children from the `description` element. It will not include the `p` elements or descendents thereof, as requested.